# How do I deploy to multiple sites using Web Deploy?

Tags: web, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am looking at MSDeploy and I see in the documentation that you can replicate sites easily. We are not ready to use the Web Farm Framework yet so that is not an option. Is there any provider I could use to deploy to 3 servers?

Answer (score 2):

While there isn’t a provider to deploy to separate servers, the most straightforward approach would be to use the same Web Deploy command three times, just changing the [computerName](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569001%28WS.10%29.aspx) and credential settings in the destination argument to specify a different server each time.

Here's a sample command that uses the [apphostConfig](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569080%28WS.10%29.aspx) provider:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:apphostconfig="Default Web Site" -dest:apphostconfig="Default Web Site",computername=Server2,username=admin,password=xyz
```

To make the command more flexible, you could parameterize settings that you want to be different for different destination servers. More information on parameterization can be found in the articles [Web Deploy Parameterization in Action](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010_07_01_archive.html), [Web Deploy Parameterization](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1082/web-deploy-parameterization/), and [Using declareParam and setParam](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569084%28WS.10%29.aspx) .

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988832/management-of-sensitive-data-in-web-config-release-for-open-source-projects-when

The best thing would be if you create a small powershell script that:
1. Build a package for your site
2. Deploys to n servers

I'm using psake for managing task in powershell but it's plain powershell so you can just keep the lines for the package and deploy from my example above. You'll need to modify the last part of the publish task to consider the authentication to your server